# JDBC MYSQL SyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, sphinx

I am executing the following queries with JDBC/SphinxQL (Sphinx version 2.01 Beta)

with a WHERE clause:

```
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM myindex WHERE MATCH('name')");
```

without a WHERE CLAUSE

```
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM myindex");
```

But in both scenarios, I am getting the following pretty huge error:

```
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected WHERE, expecting $end near
 'WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 
'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout'
 OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 
'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection'
 OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name 
= 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation'
 OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name
 = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' 
OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 
'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names'
 OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR
 Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 
'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' 
OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect''
```

I don't understand the error at all...help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you run sphinx in some kind of debug mode and get it to log the real SQL it is executing before executing it?

Comment: I am having trouble EVEN connecting to sphinxql in java... what is your code? please help

Answer (score 1):

SphinxQL can't recognize different clauses such us
timezone, interactive_timeout, net_write_timeout etc That is why these queries failed. You have to use different MySQL client that doesn't post such unnedded stuff - just your plain query. Or you could try SphinxSerach services to point the developers to that issue.

Comment: what do you mean "different MySQL client"? do you mean a different version of MySQL? Also how do I check to see if the MySQL version posts all that stuff or not...Thanks!

Comment: I mean different library or version of that client as I know that java client set different flags on handshake or during request based on server version.

Comment: You'll see that only when you got no errors. Because Sphinx could parse this query SELECT * FROM YOUR_INDEX but stuck with error on that query SELECT * FROM YOUR_INDEX OPTION character_set_connection='utf8'

Comment: So you mean a different version of MySQL (Connector/J)?

Comment: Yes at first different versions of Connector/J or set\reset some flags to prevent "smart" mode of Connector/J Then try something different. I don't now java much but for .net there are many alternatives to Connector/.NET

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly formatted your [MATCH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) predicate.

Change:

```
SELECT * FROM myindex WHERE MATCH('name')
```

To

```
SELECT * FROM myindex WHERE MATCH(some_column) AGAINST ('name')
```

Comment: algorithmicCoder is using SphinxQL not straight MySQSL. Thinks are different there.